# android animation does not work when animation is turned off in the developer settings

Tags: android, animation

I'm creating my first android game and i'm using objectanimator for all the animations in the game. I now realized that if the animation is turned off in the developer settings on the device the animations does not work. In other games the animation is still working... Is there a way to animate objects and it could not be disabled through the developer settings?

Thanks

Comment: Using the canvas, or using OpenGL. If you're just a beginner, I'd recommend you learn about the canvas. It's much easier to learn than OpenGL. Otherwise, you could look for an existing game engine like AndEngine/AndEngineExamples or Unity3D.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, i've already implemented most of the app. Is there a workaround for that? ... I don't want to start it all over again.

Comment: It really depends on the kind of game you're making. Nobody is forcing you to use the Canvas or OpenGL. Also, no one is going to turn on developer mode and then turn off animation. Or even if they are, you could just check for that and tell them to turn animations back on.

Comment: I think i'll just pop up a message to notify them about it. Thanks